# SQL Server Linux Change COLLATION

Tags: sql-server, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a SQL server which is triggered inside docker container from gitlab. Following yaml file does that :

```
services:
    - name: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
      alias: mssql
  variables:
    MSSQL_HOST: microsoft-mssql-server-linux
    ACCEPT_EULA: Y
    MSSQL_COLLATION: Latin1_General_CS_AS
    SA_PASSWORD: yourStrong(!)Password
```

Now when i am starting this pipeline its giving error in running the sql script saying that login failed for user SA . Error is as :

> $ /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P
> "yourStrong(!)Password" -i Scripts/DBScript.sql Sqlcmd: Error:
> Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'SA'..
> Cleaning up file based variables ERROR: Job failed: command terminated
> with exit code 1

This error gets resolved once i remove the collation **"MSSQL_COLLATION:Latin1_General_CS_AS"** from the yaml file.
This explains that i am not able to change MSSQL Serve collation.

Note: Container spawned by Gitlab is Linux Container which is also installing docker image of **"mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"**.

Any idea how to change Collation level at MS SQL server level.

Comment: Pretty the reason is because you are using `SA`, but have chosen to use a Case **Sensitive** collation. As such, your `LOGIN`s will be case sensitive too, and thus no `LOGIN` is found with the name `SA`; because `SA` and `sa` are not the same. If you are going to use a Case Sensitive Collation for the instance, you need to be careful with your casing.

Comment: What should be workaround here then need this collation only MSSQL_COLLATION:Latin1_General_CS_AS

Comment: There is no "workaround", the solution is spell the `LOGIN` name correctly... `sa` <> `SA` in a case sensitive collation. Correct your script to use the correct login name.

Comment: The script is executed in as : "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA" is this user name specified SA going to sa ??

Comment: But the `LOGIN` is ***`sa`*** not `SA`...

Comment: Yeah got it this Collation MSSQL_COLLATION:Latin1_General_CS_AS did all this stuff.
Thanks a lot